# Azure DevOps REST API with OAuth HTTP 203 Non-Authoritative Information

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, microsoft-entra-id

I have an Entra ID app that have API Permission `user_impersonation` for Azure DevOps resource.

[image]

I try to get the token:

**Getting code**

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<appId>&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&
response_mode=query&
scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
```

**Getting token**

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=<clientId>&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=<code>&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms
&client_secret=<secret>&
scope=offline_access%20499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798%2F.default
```

I managed to get the token, however, when trying to request Azure DevOps API, I keep getting HTTP 203.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/<organization>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0-preview.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

I tried to look for a solution, but most of the solutions I came across suggest using PAT, I follow some of the solution that uses OAuth, but I keep getting HTTP 203, I can't figure out what I did differently that caused this issue.

Update:

**Making request**

`https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7`
[image]

My token after using the `scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` (redacted to show important fields)

```
{
  "aud": "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>/",
  "iat": 1705408896,
  "nbf": 1705408896,
  "exp": 1705413139,
  "acr": "1",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "appid": "<app Id>",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "email": "<email>",
  "idp": "live.com",
  "scp": "user_impersonation",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the 203 error using your scripts. Changing the scope in "Getting token" from `scope=offline_access%20499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798%2F.default` to `scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` can resolve the issue.

Using the bearer token in REST API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to list all the builds in one project. It works fine.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've try with the scope you suggested, after get the token, I still getting HTTP 203 in Postman, I've updated the question to include that. I'm using personal account to sign up for the Azure DevOps, not sure if that make any different, but the Azure Boards Slack apps works for me though.

Comment: 1. Is the DevOps organization connected to the Azure directory which contains your Entra ID app? 2. Please try to use other account in your organization to login to your app and get a new code, then use this code to get token. Check if there is the same error or not.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT: I am also getting the exact error (203) with the same test case. My DevOps organization is connected to Azure Entra where the Entra ID app is registered. Can you explain what you mean by your point 2 above? So far I have not been able to find any support material that can solve this 203 error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved it so I thought I would share my answer here. @ZiyangLiu-MSFT provided the correct suggestion to obtain the bearer token but what most blogs don't talk about is the permission you need to set up on the Azure DevOps side as well. For me to get this Entra Id to work, I need to set the correct permission in the Azure DevOps side. In my case, I set it in Azure DevOps -> Projects -> Teams to allow the permission to this Entra ID.

Comment: Please [edit] to reduce the "Me too" impression. Ideally try for [answer].

Answer (score 0):

After much testing and repeatedly getting the same response - 203 Non-Authoritative Information - the most consistent fix I've seen is to make sure the token you've received hasn't expired. It only has a lifetime of just under 1 hour.

Also make sure you're using the right scope as a header when getting your token. As suggested by Ziyang Liu-MSFT it is: **499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default**